# How do I access an AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption's properties in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, tvos

So I'm working with a video that has subtitle tracks and I'm trying to access the name and language code of each one to display in a menu. Currently I'm doing:

```
AVMediaSelectionGroup *selectionGroup = [self.currentAsset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicLegible];
NSArray *subtitles = selectionGroup.options;
self.subtitlesOptions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@{ @"label": @"Off", @"value": @"off" }];

for(AVMediaSelectionOption *track in subtitles) {
    NSString *title = track.displayName; // This isn't right
    NSString *language = track.locale.localeIdentifier;
    [self.subtitlesOptions addObject:@{ @"label":title, @"value":language }];
}
```

When I print each `track` object I get something like below.

```
<AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x171c79c40, language = engcc, mediaType = 'sbtl', title = English Closed Captions>
```

I can get the language properly, but the problem is that `displayName` doesn't correlate with `title` and in this case it actually returns "engcc" instead of "English Closed Captions". Is there any way to get the `title`?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this? I am looking for a way to access another parameter but it might be the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution for your question. Working fine. Hope this will help.

```
for(AVMediaSelectionOption *track in subtitles) {
                NSString *language = nil;
                NSArray *contents = [AVMetadataItem metadataItemsFromArray:[mediaSelectionOption commonMetadata] withKey:AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle keySpace:AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon];
                if ([contents count] > 0)
                {

                    NSArray *titlesForPreferredLanguages = [AVMetadataItem metadataItemsFromArray:contents filteredAndSortedAccordingToPreferredLanguages:[NSLocale preferredLanguages]];
                    if ([titlesForPreferredLanguages count] > 0)
                    {
                        language = [[titlesForPreferredLanguages objectAtIndex:0] extendedLanguageTag];
                    }

                    if (language == nil)
                    {
                        language = [[contents objectAtIndex:0] extendedLanguageTag];
                    }
                }

    }
```